# Can Finder show dates including seconds?

Tags: macos

Can you make Finder show timestamps with hour:minutes:seconds?.  It seemed to be possible in old versions of OS X, judging by this post:
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/show-date-created-down-to-seconds.569085/

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has changed, except that the location within System Preference has had a name change.

You can do this as follows:

1. Got to Apple > System Preferences...
2. Select the Language & Region preference pane
3. Click the <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> button at bottom left
4. Select the <kbd>Times</kbd> tab
5. You'll see the *Short* format fields at top
6. Edit this field by dragging the 'Second' time element from the Time Elements area to the Short field (**Note:** You'll need to manually enter the colon (:) in between the mins and secs if you was it to be displayed as well)
7. Click on <kbd>OK</kbd>
8. Exit System Preferences

Now you'll have the seconds displayed in your Finder time stamps.

Comment: you're the absolute Master and Commander, thanks a lot

Comment: @Antonio23249 If this answered your question, should you not accept it?