# Show Finder item Modified / Created time with seconds in Ventura

Tags: finder, ventura

In previous version of Mac OS before Ventura, it was an easy fix to allow Finder and other applications to show date created / modified time including seconds with this method here: [Can Finder show dates including seconds?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329034/can-finder-show-dates-including-seconds?newreg=00bef1353a5f456782a910bc09979338)

Since updating my existing system that had these preference set now to Ventura, Finder no longer shows the seconds that items were created or modified and the options to highly customize time in the Region settings are missing.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found a workaround based on the sources in the question link that was mentioned in my opening question.

Entering the following in Terminal followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> will make changes to `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` (this is a hidden file revealed with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> if manually browsed to in a Finder window via **Go** > **Go to Folder**)

`defaults write -g AppleICUTimeFormatStrings -dict-add 1 "hh':'mm':'ss' 'a"`

After force-quit restarting the Finder, the desired time format with seconds is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

@steve-m's solution works for all user accounts due to writing a key to the "global domain" of "UserDefaults". If you would like to display seconds in date format for date properties of a file in the Finder app, then log in to your account and execute the following command in the Terminal app:

for current user:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist AppleICUTimeFormatStrings -dict-add 1 "hh':'mm':'ss' 'a"
```

for all users:

```
defaults write -g AppleICUTimeFormatStrings -dict-add 1 "hh':'mm':'ss' 'a"
```

This solution uses the "application domain" preferences file of the Finder app instead of the "global domain, " which limits it to the Finder app of the current user only.

To find out other date formatting options, visit the following link: [nsdateformatter.com](https://nsdateformatter.com)